# IE9 Javascript classList Property

Tags: javascript

IE9 doesn't support the classList property is there anyway around this line of javascript for it to work in IE9

```
this.wrap.classList.add("myClass")
```

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=classlist+polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are polyfills, but if you don't want to use one: Since `className` is a space-separated list of the classes, you could use a regular expression:

```
return /(?:^|\s)myClass(?:$|\s)/.test(document.body.className);
```

(Sadly, we can't just use `\b` [word boundary] since `-` qualifies as a word boundary, but isn't a separator in the class list.)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```js
const hasClass = ($element, className) => {
  const match = new RegExp(`(^|\\s)${className}(\\s|$)`).test($element.className);
  return $element.className && match;
};

const $el = document.querySelector('.foo');

alert(hasClass($el, 'foo'));
```

```css
.foo {
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Foobar</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Building on the previous answers, if you don't want to have to deal with the nitty gritty of regexes yourself, you could import jQuery and use jQuery's `.hasClass()` method instead.

```
return $(document.body).hasClass("myClass");
```

jQuery handles dealing with cross-browser support.

Comment: So I can know for next time, why the downvote? I'm pretty sure the jQuery .hasClass method does do what the OP wants